# How can I wrap href to multiple elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, word-wrap

I'm trying to add a href tag and get the value of a div because I need to add that value on the href tag using jQuery, I have this code

```
<div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">book
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-item odd">pencil
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to do this:

```
<div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">
        <a href="search/book">book</a>
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-item odd">
        <a href="search/pencil">pencil</a>
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could you please help me

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov Did you read the question? He's not trying to change the href of a hyperlink, he's trying to add the hyperlink.

Comment: @skycomputer2 you can use jquery map also to learn new things in jquery.
my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39305892/6608101

Answer (score 4):

You need to use .wrap function. More: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Here the code:

```
$('.field-item').each(function(){

// to get text and remove any unwanted space
var link = $(this).text().trim(); 
$(this).wrap('<a href="search/'+ link +'"></a>');

});
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljvjvbkq/23/

Comment: You should use `.text().trim()`, because he has whitespace after the text.

Comment: thats that works but know i have to do a change i have to add a href tag before text:
<div class="field-item even"><a href="search/book">book</a><div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>

Comment: @skycomputer2, you changed your questions, my answer was correct according to your old questions. Now answer will be different. but problem is if people see my current answer with your question then they will give me negative( - ) vote which is not fair. You could make request without changing the questions and accept this answer first.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('.field-item').each(function(){
        var search = $(this).text().trim();
        $(this).wrap('<a href="search/' + search + '"></a>');
      });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/obLzf5st/1/

Comment: Ruhul Amin - You have copyed my solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with Map function [jquery map](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```js
var a = $("<a />");
$('.field-items > div.field-item').map(function(){
  $(this)
    .wrap($(a)
    .attr('href','search/'+$(this).text().trim()));  
   return $(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">book
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-item odd">pencil
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">book-new
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-item odd">pencil-new
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```